# How can I update datagridview after Rows are delete

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms, datatable

I have two tables with foreign key,
first one is:

**tblFile** : FileID, FileName...

And the second one is:

**tblChild** (in Datagridview) : ChildID, ChildName, ChildBirthDate, fkFileID.

> When the `Save` button (in the Form) is clicked then how can I update all the rows in second table if rows are deleted?
> (Form ex: https://i.postimg.cc/jq7Ks3CW/1.jpg)

[image]

I tried DataRow and others but no result. Please help.

This is full code:

```
public void dgvChildUpdate(DataGridView dgv, TextBox txtID)
{
    string ChID;
    DataTable dtNew = (DataTable)dgv.DataSource;
    DataTable dtDel = dtNew.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);

    if (dtDel != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtDel.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblFileChild WHERE ChildID = @ChildID", ClsDB.con);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildID", dtDel.Rows[i]["ChildID"].ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    dtDel = null;

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblChild WHERE fkFileID = @FileID", ClsDB.con))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileID", txtID.Text);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int t = 0; t < dt.Rows.Count; t++)
            {
                ChID = dt.Rows[t]["ChildID"].ToString();
                for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (ChID == dgv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmdChild = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblChild SET ChildName = @ChildName, ChildBirthDate = @ChildBirthDate WHERE ChildID = @ChildID", ClsDB.con))
                        {
                            cmdChild.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildID", dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                            cmdChild.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildName", dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                            cmdChild.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildBirthDate", dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                            cmdChild.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow rowCh in dgv.Rows)
        {
            ChID = rowCh.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            if (ChID == string.Empty)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmdChild = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblChild (ChildName, ChildBirthDate, fkFileID) VALUES (@ChildName, @ChildBirthDate, (SELECT FileID FROM tblFile WHERE FileID = @FileID))", ClsDB.con))
                {
                    cmdChild.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildName", rowCh.Cells[1].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmdChild.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildBirthDate", rowCh.Cells[3].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmdChild.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileID", txtID.Text.Trim());
                    cmdChild.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share some code where you are having some issue. Otherwise it would be a wild guess for the people trying to help you here.
If the `save` button is clicked you add a new data or delete a data. Why don't you reload the table after clicking the save button or delete button?

Comment: See now full code. i tried also dataAdapter update for all but i can not do it :(

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using EF LINQ for your operations? Also, normalizing database tables its not as common as you think in the real world.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. can you give a example for EF LINQ?